# Bind database connection to a thread

Tags: java, database

I've seen two ways to deal with database connections:
1) Connection pool
2) Bind connection to a thread (when we have fixed and constant threads count)

But I don't undestand what is the purpose of using #2. What are the advantagase of the second behaviour over the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with a single thread or a very small set of threads (that need database functionality), binding a connection to a thread would act like a poor man's connection pool. Instead of checking out a connection from the pool every time you use it, you would just use the single connection bound to the thread. This would allow for quick execution of database queries, even with code that hasn't been very well designed.

However in many cases you're not working with a single thread or a small set of threads. As soon as you're developing an application with even dozens of simultaneous users, you're better off working with a connection pool as it will become impossible to dedicate a connection to every thread (see next paragraph).

Some people also have the misunderstanding that a connection pool can and should have a lot of connections (100 or more), even though it's often more advantageous to have fewer. Since all of the connections use the database's resources, the effect is similar to having a store with a single cash register. It's not more efficient to have 10 doors to the store instead of 1, since it will just fill up with customers but the payments won't happen any faster.